# GWAS : input files for rrBLUP package in R

Tags: gwas

I want to do a verification of the result of an RNAseq analysis of human cancer samples by GWAS, I want to use rrBLUP package in R, so I need three input file genotype, phenotype and mapping file, so I am confused about how I can get these files.